# SQL statement to update a table based on foreign keys

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE animals
       SET dog = dog + 1
       from animal_names, color
       WHERE animal_names.name = "Buddy" and color.name = "Yellow";
```

Essentially, I want to add 1 to the count of dogs on the table "animals". However, animals uses the foreign keys "animal_names" and "color". However, I want to update animals without using the ids of these foreign keys, instead wishing to use a string as opposed to their id.

Comment: huh? Have you got 3 tables (animals, animal_names, color)? What is the link between them?

Comment: I think the question is not clear. You should first explain what are your table structures, how are the FK relations, an then explain what you need and give the code example, and also mentioning if its working but you need a improvement, of it is triggering an error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the relation in the `from` section of your 'update`.   For example:

```
UPDATE animals
SET dog = dog + 1
FROM animals 
  INNER JOIN animal_names 
    ON animals.nameID = animal_names.nameID
  INNER JOIN color 
    ON animals.colorID = color.colorID
WHERE 
  animal_names.name = "Buddy"
   AND
  color.name = "Yellow" ;
```

(assuming, for this example, that your primary keys are like-named integers as above.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't work out your table structure - I can't quite see how you'd have dog count on an animals table so I'll take a guess.

```
UPDATE animals
       SET dog = dog + (
        select count(*) 
       from animal_names inner join color on (whatever)
       WHERE animal_names.name = "Buddy" and
       color.name = "Yellow" and 
       animal_names.animaltype='dog'
      )
```

Probably not quite right but may help you out.